# Using inlineformset_factory with different querysets in CreateView

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use inlineformset_factory to create instances of the same model.

**models.py**

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_skills")
    technology = models.ForeignKey(Technology, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField('common year using amount ', max_length=4)
    last_year = models.CharField('Last year of technology using ', max_length=4)
    level = models.CharField("experience level", max_length=64, choices=LEVELS)

class Techgroup(models.Model):
    """ Group of technology """

    name = models.CharField('group_name', max_length=32, unique=True)



class Technology(models.Model):
    """Technologies."""

    name = models.CharField('technology name', max_length=32, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Techgroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group")
```

In the Administrator pane I created 2 instances of the Techgroup model:
- **Framework**
- **Programming language**

All **Skill** models belong to one of two groups. On the front I display 2 forms, one containing queryset with instances belonging to the Framework, the other with instances belonging to the Programming language. 
I divide Querysets using ModelsForm:

**forms.py**

```
class SkillBaseCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(1, 11)]
    LAST_YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(2015, datetime.datetime.now().year + 1)]
    year = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=YEAR_CHOICES),
    )
    last_year = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=LAST_YEAR_CHOICES))

    class Meta:

        model = Skill
        fields = ['technology', 'level', 'last_year', 'year']


class SkillCreatePLanguageForm(SkillBaseCreateForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SkillCreatePLanguageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Programming language")


class SkillCreateFrameworkForm(SkillBaseCreateForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SkillCreateFrameworkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Framework")

SkillFrameworkFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employee, Skill, form=SkillCreateFrameworkForm, extra=1, can_delete=False)

SkillPLanguageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employee, Skill, form=SkillCreatePLanguageForm, extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class SkillTestCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):
    """
    Create new skill instances
    """

    template_name = 'edit.html'
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeEditForm

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Handles GET requests and instantiates blank versions of the form
            and its inline formsets.
        """
        self.object = Employee.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        form_framework = SkillFrameworkFormSet()
        form_language = SkillPLanguageFormSet()

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  form_framework=form_framework,
                                  form_language=form_language))


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
        formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
        validity.
        """
        self.object = Employee.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        form_framework = SkillFrameworkFormSet(self.request.POST)
        form_language = SkillPLanguageFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and form_framework.is_valid() and
                form_language.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, form_framework, form_language)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, form_framework, form_language)

    def form_valid(self, form, form_framework, form_language):
        """
        Called if all forms are valid. Creates a Employee instance along with
        associated models and then redirects to a
        success page.
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        form_framework.instance = self.object
        form_framework.save()
        form_language.instance = self.object
        form_language.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('profile', args=[self.kwargs['pk']]))

    def form_invalid(self, form, form_framework, form_language):
        """
        Called if a form is invalid. Re-renders the context data with the
        data-filled forms and errors.
        """
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  form_framework=form_framework,
                                  form_language=form_language,
                                  ))
```

The problem is that I always get an error message when I submit a form:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

The problem is that when I submit a form, I always get an error message in the technology field of the queryset which is displayed first in the template. 
That is, if the template

```
{form_framework}}
{form_language}
```

a mistake on

```
queryset = Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Framework"
```

if

```
{form_language}
 {form_framework}}
```

a mistake on

```
queryset = Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Programming language"
```

If I leave only one form in views.py, everything starts to work.

I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days and I think I'm at a dead end. Need help!